# End of line in text file - C++

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I don't know how to implement this algorithm

//you have a text file like

```
12 3
3
4 4
```

1. if the line contains only one number skip it
   else
2. read first number then the second number and do some work

So, How can I know that the line is end?
I need to deal with the data as integer not string

Comment: Look up a few file IO functions, like `fgets()` or `fstream.getline()`.

Comment: You should provide some code. SO isn't a homework achiever.

Comment: So read it in as a string and the *convert* the strings to `int`s

Answer (score 1):

Please consult a tutorial such as [cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)

From the above tutorial:

```
 string line;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      cout << line << '\n';
    }
    myfile.close();
  }
```

Quick explanation: The 'getline' returns true, until the end of file is not reached.

Answer (score 1):

run this program and see what is happening. it should be very straight forward.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

     ifstream ifs;
     ifs.open("input.txt");

     string line;

     while (getline(ifs, line))
     {

        cout<<"whole line is: "<<line<<endl;
         //can seperate input:
         istringstream is(line);
         int numberOnLine;

         is>>numberOnLine;
         vector<int> myvec;

         while(is)
         {
             myvec.push_back(numberOnLine);
             is>>numberOnLine;
         }

         if(myvec.size()<2)
         {
             cout<<"this line had less than 2 numbers ";
         }
         else{
            cout<<"the line had at least 2 numbers, here they are: ";
            for(int i=0; i<myvec.size(); ++i) cout<<myvec.at(i)<<" ";
         }
         cout<<endl;
     }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time , If I read it as string or char how can deal with it as number ?

Comment: simple, instead of string substring, you can do int substring. I will update answer for you

Answer (score 0):

The end of a line is symbolized by the character `'\n'`.

So When you read your file, you have to look for `'\n'` character, and you will be able to find out what belong to which line.

**PROCESS**

1. Extract a first sample from your file
2. Put it in a buffer
3. Split the buffer on `'\n'` character
4. Analyze each line to keep only the ones with 2 number